# length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: error-handling, package

I am new to using R and actually to most programming language, so I am a bit lost here. Hope you can help. I am using RCMap for whcih I have 4csv documents, I get the following error code:
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
I am sure it has something to do with my own data, because I get normal output if I use other people´s data. However, I don´t know where the problem is (not even in which of the four documents). I do have a lot of missing data, however changing the missing data to either blank spaces or NA, does not change the error code.
The documents of other people that I am able to run also contain missing data, although to a lesser extend.

Hope you can help,

best wishes, Doriene

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it helped when i put a space in front of c__bacilli.

Ex: test <- subset_taxa(phylo, Class==" c__Bacilli")